# Running google cloud datalab on GKE

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-cloud-datalab

I deployed datalab to my GKE cluster:

```
kubectl run datalab --image gcr.io/cloud-datalab/datalab:latest --port 8081
```

Then I tried forwarding (`kubectl port-forward`) a local port to port 8081 on the datalab pod, but requests are not reaching the pod.

What am I my missing ? Is it due to IP address binding issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely need to try attaching to port 8080 instead of 8081, as that is the port the webserver inside the container runs against.

See also my answer here: https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1633